# ArrayAdapter with Spinner returning android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner, android-resources

I trying to populate a Spinner with a List of Strings. He compiles and run in android, but when I enter a touch in the Spinner, the program stops and return this error:

android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f090003 type #0x12 is not valid

```
protected void onPostExecute(List<String> myList)
        {
            if (!myList.isEmpty())
            {
                ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, myList);
                adp.setDropDownViewResource(R.id.mySpinner);
                mySpinner.setAdapter(adp);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Warning.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(myActivity.this, Preferences.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `setDropDownViewResource` method expects a layout resource ID.

You should replace

```
adp.setDropDownViewResource(R.id.mySpinner);
```

by

```
adp.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.mySpinner);
```

And make sure (of course) that the file `res/layout/mySpinner.xml` exists

Or just use a default layout from the SDK:

```
adp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Comment: But I using the layout file of android.R. that comes with the Android SDK. Right?

Comment: I'm not talking about `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` (which is perfectly correct), but about the line after

Comment: See my edit: you can use the default `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` if you want

Comment: The answer was in my front, and I can't see... Thank you.